# When printing an Object (with Cura) the Hole disappears

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I created an object (gear with hole) to print with my 3D printer.
I don't know the reason but when I want to print it, the hole of gear disappears.

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. You can upload .blend files to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and then use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136159/edit) below your question to add the given link to your question. You can also  [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to help us understand your problem.

Comment: i edited the question @metaphor_set

Comment: I don't know much about 3D printing, but I found 32 double vertices in your mesh. Go to edit mode, hit "A" on your keyboard to select everything, then hit "W" and select "Remove Doubles". Maybe that's the source of your problem.

Comment: nothing :((( i don't understand

Comment: the problem is not solved like your suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have geometry made out of a few separate closed volumes that are overlapping:

[image]

That is definitely not a good idea. You should have one continuous volume per object. I can only guess how your printing process works, however the printer will probably need a continuous volume so the software is probably trying to automatically guess what it is using Boolean operations that do not work well with overlapping geometry that is also present in the model. You should simply model the object as a single continuous volume that has one continuous surface that does not overlap with itself. You should not have any overlapping geometry(vertices, edges or faces), there should also be no holes or non-manifold geometry in your models if you wish to avoid problems when 3d printing. In some cases printing software may fix the issues automatically, but obviously, if you wish the process to work every time as expected, you should ensure the geometry is tidy and suitable for printing in the first place.

Comment: hmm now understand... i used more object to have a central hole, because modifier "boolean" makes same problem (the hole is not printed)